# ¿Cómo visualizar documento en un cuadro de dialogo para "Política de privacidad" desde el servidor?

Tags: android, android-widget

Estoy desarollando una app la cual hace uso de un Login. 
Debido a esto me gustaría mostrar por medio de una ventana flotante la Política de privacidad y las condiciones de uso.

El documento lo tengo guardado en Firebase storage (tambien en google drive). Me proguntaba si han implementado algo parecido en sus apps.

En caso contrario, que metodo me recoiendan para mostrar estos documentos?
Podria simplemente redirigir a un link de una pagina web, desgraciadamente aun no tengo programada la web para la app. Es por eso que me gustaria que se mostrara todo en la misma app.

Muchas gracias y saludos.

Comment: Tienes razon, no se me habia ocurrido hacer eso. Lo pobrare a ver que tan estetico se ve. Gracias :)

Comment: te lo pongo como respuesta asi la aceptas si te sirvio :)

Answer (score 0):

No seria tanta complejidad, solo guarda los terminos en un `String` dentro de Firebase y en el `dialog.setMessage()` le pasas el resultado desde Firebase, si pones tu estructura de firebase puedo darte una mano